Generate GCP auth identity-token in JAVA
I am looking for ways to generate GCP identity token in Java. I am able to generate it via the gcloud cli like this ./bin/gcloud auth print-identity-token. But couldn't find a way to do something similar with the Java Client.
Please share some insights on how this needs to be created.
Thanks in advance.

Might help. https://github.com/karlnicholas/bff

So, in my case the target audience url is something like this XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com I obtained the URL by decoding the token that I generated using the command gcloud auth print-identity-token.
I used this code to extract it,
import base64

token = '##update your token here"

b64_profile = token.split('.')[1]

profile = base64.b64decode(b64_profile + '=' * (-len(b64_profile) % 4))

print(profile)


please consider these following ways just as they are in the doc.
Generate_tokens_programmatically

import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.IdTokenCredentials;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.IdTokenProvider;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Authentication {

  // makeGetRequest makes a GET request to the specified Cloud Run or
  // Cloud Functions endpoint `serviceUrl` (must be a complete URL), by
  // authenticating with an ID token retrieved from Application Default
  // Credentials using the specified `audience`.
  //
  // For Cloud Functions, endpoint (`serviceUrl`) and `audience` are the same.
  // Example `audience` value (Cloud Functions): https://project-region-projectid.cloudfunctions.net/myFunction
  public static HttpResponse makeGetRequest(String serviceUrl, String audience) throws IOException {
    GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();
    if (!(credentials instanceof IdTokenProvider)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Credentials are not an instance of IdTokenProvider.");
    }
    IdTokenCredentials tokenCredential =
        IdTokenCredentials.newBuilder()
            .setIdTokenProvider((IdTokenProvider) credentials)
            .setTargetAudience(audience)
            .build();

    GenericUrl genericUrl = new GenericUrl(serviceUrl);
    HttpCredentialsAdapter adapter = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(tokenCredential);
    HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
    HttpRequest request = transport.createRequestFactory(adapter).buildGetRequest(genericUrl);
    return request.execute();
  }
}


Generate tokens manually

If you're invoking a function and for some
reason you cannot use the authentication libraries, there are two ways
you can get the ID token manually, either using the Compute metadata
server or by creating a self-signed JWT and exchanging it for a
Google-signed ID token.

Also
Provide your request with authentication credentials as a Google-generated ID token stored in an Authorization header. For example, get an ID token using gcloud by running the following command:

curl  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" \ https://FUNCTION_URL

where FUNCTION_URL is the URL of your function. Retrieve this URL from the Cloud Functions page of the Google Cloud console or by running the gcloud functions describe command as shown in the first step of the Google Cloud CLI deployment command example.
for only during development :
get-id-token#generic-dev
You can use the gcloud CLI to get an ID token for your user credentials that can be used with any Cloud Run service or Cloud Function that the caller has the required IAM permissions to invoke. This token will not work for any other application.
Warning: be sure to keep these tokens secure, and never use them in a production environment. They are meant to be used during development only.
To generate a generic ID token, you use the gloud auth print-identity-token command:
gcloud auth print-identity-token

How do you find what the target audience should be?

in this case it should be the URL of the cloud function endpoint , something like https://function-url/projects/project-id/locations/region/functions/function-name also going through  generate-bearer-token-for-google-cloud-function-java might be helpful. try and let us know
